# Find Max date prior to specific date and min date after specific date for each ID

Tags: excel, max, formula, vlookup, min

i have a list of ID's in one tab along with a start date and end date, Col A,B,C respectively. In a second tab I have a list of ID's, along with a due date in column B. There are duplicates in the second tab. I need to lookup the ID from the first tab, and return the max due date from the second tab prior to the start date. Also looking to do the opposite. Lookup the ID from the first tab and return the first date(min) after the end date. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: What have you tried?  This is not a free code-writing service but we can help you with what you are trying to develop. I suggest you read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then  either edit your original question to improve it, or ask a new one if the original has been closed.

Comment: I've looked into lookups, match, index. But I dont know how to do what I'm looking to do. Hence my question. As for as my question, I'm fairly certain it's easy to understand and straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

**Apply the below formulas and drag down as needed**

---

Max Due Date (*Prior To Start Date*) `=MAXIFS(H:H,G:G,A2,H:H,"<"&B2)`
Min Due Date (*After End Date*) `=MINIFS(H:H,G:G,A2,H:H,">"&C2)`

[image]

Comment: I tried maxifs as I found an article about that, but i just get a #name error.

Comment: So you prob done have the maxims formula. You can find how to do this with array formulas

Comment: How would I go about adding that to excel? I'm running 2016 and from what ive seen it should be available?

Comment: excuse the typos on last comment lol was on phone. Does the formula pop up as you are typing it in? If not, then you don't have it.

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately.